# xdotool scripting, vmware interference

Tags: linux, vmware, gui

So I have a small gui program I need to automate as part of a build process. I'm working in Fedora 10, and unfortunately the gui program is a windows program I'm running through wine and wine crashes if I try to run the gui program as a command line version.

So I scripted the gui program with xdotool.
Now for a tale of 3 Linux installations

1. Fedora 10 on a dedicated machine. The xdotool script works flawlessly every time.
2. Fedora 10 running under vmware with a Linux Mint host. The xdotool script works flawlessly every time.
3. Fedora 10 running under vmware in Windows 10. The xdotool script works some of the time.

The Fedora 10 installs are all identical. Any idea why the one running under vmware in Windows 10 only works some of the time?

Here's the script making xdotool's calls. I put all the `sleep`'s in because I thought maybe it was taking a second to launch to gui program and it was missing some events, or possibly events were being sent too fast.

```
#!/bin/bash
`./MMTOOL_3.22_1B_21Fix-BKMODE.EXE&`&
sleep 4
wid=`xdotool search --name "MMTOOL"`
sleep 0.1
xdotool windowactivate $wid
sleep 0.1
xdotool windowfocus $wid
echo $wid
xdotool windowmove $wid 0 0
sleep 0.25
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.75
xdotool type "bioses\innocore\DPX410_CUSTOMCF.BIN"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.1
xdotool type "bin\optbios.rom"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.75
xdotool mousemove 55 134
sleep 0.1
xdotool click 1
sleep 0.75
xdotool type "bin\410_bios"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
sleep 0.75
xdotool key "Tab"
sleep 0.1
xdotool key "space"
```

Comment: About the only thing I can see that would relate is VMware Tools (all other VM components are isolate). Does your tool use underlying structures for Video, Mouse, or File Sharing?

Comment: I originally tried making xlib calls directly. Pretty much same result, works on my end, doesn't work on the windows' hosted vm. I figured maybe I wasn't making the calls correctly, so I used xdotool which is made for generating xwindows events. I figured it'd make the calls correctly.

Comment: Fire sharing's not used. I'm using xdotool to send mostly key presses, one mouse movement and one mouse click. I believe xdotool makes xlib calls under the hood.

Comment: What if sometimes a short timing (`sleep 0.1`) isn't enough?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, but it was working on my two linux installs without them. I only add them as extra to run on the windows vm. The 0.1 ones are for tabbing around a dialog box and the 0.75 ones are for opening and closing a dialog.